# Why retryWhen hides errors from handler if subscribed in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I got `retryWhen` usage which is needed to do some request in case of server error. This is simplified by such synthetic code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Single.error<Int>(Exception("Source"))
            .retryWhen {
                it.flatMapSingle {
                    Single
                            .error<Unit>(Exception("Handler"))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .doOnError { handlerError -> handlerError.printStackTrace() }
                }
            }
            .subscribe({ println("success") }, 
            { 
               println("source error")
               it.printStackTrace() 
            })
}
```

Here source produces error then it should be re-subscribed using `retryWhen` when handler's request is complete.

But handler occurs an error! Then `retryWhen` is designed not to throw out to source chain and handle error state as "no retry". But no matter of `retryWhen` handler expected to output in `doOnError` and there is nothing, handler error is hidden.

On Java:

- error is *put out to source chain* if not changing schedulers - no `subscribeOn`.
- error is *hidden* - no `doOnError` call if subscribed on computation.

On Android:

- also error is *put out to source chain* if not changing schedulers - no `subscribeOn`.
- *hidden* if subscribed on computation, no matter observed on main or not

Why `doOnError` is not processed when running on background?

Why `retryWhen` does not swallow errors if not changing schedulers?

Comment: I don't fully understand your sentences. If you have a main method and an asynchronous sequence like that background error handling, the program quits before doing anything as RxJava uses daemon threads. Could you turn your cases into unit tests so it becomes clear what your expectations are?

Comment: OK, Java case can be not usable because of early finishing daemons. Then such fun can be called from Android and I expect that handler's `doOnError` runs every launch, but it does not, and depends on schedulers are set.